# Escoger en qué monitor se abre la app JAVA Desktop

Tags: java, jframe

Hola estoy desarrollando una **aplicación de escritorio en JAVA** para una empresa, el caso es que, casi todos **trabajan con 2 monitores a la vez** y haciendo mis pruebas de mi App, cuando la muevo para el 2do monitor funciona bien hasta que cualquier acción que implique abrir otro *Jframe* (crear un objeto nuevo *Jframe* y hacerlo visible). Se aparecen en el monitor principal.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que siempre se quede en el monitor que uno esta trabajando ya sea el 2do o el principal?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente fragmento de codigo :

```
public static void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame )
{
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if( screen > -1 && screen < gs.length )
    {
        gs[screen].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
    }
    else if( gs.length > 0 )
    {
        gs[0].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}
```

Clase VentanaB :

```
public class VentanaB extends JFrame 
{
    public VentanaB()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        setTitle("VentanaB");
    }
}
```

Clase VentanaA :

```
public class VentanaA extends JFrame
{
    public VentanaA()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        setTitle("VentanaA");

        //generamos un Button en tiempo de ejecucion al cual le indicamos que tendra un Listener de Acciones
        Button boton = new Button("nueva ventana");
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                //este fragmento de codigo de ejecutara cada vez que hagamos click en el boton
                //instanciamos la VentanaB
                VentanaB ventanaB = new VentanaB();
                //llamamos al metodo showOnScreen al cual le indicamos en que numero de monitor se debe  visualizar el Frame que enviamos como segundo parametro
                showOnScreen(2, ventanaB);
            }
        });
        add(boton);
    }

    public static void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame )
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
        if( screen > -1 && screen < gs.length )
        {
            gs[screen].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
        }
        else if( gs.length > 0 )
        {
            gs[0].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //iniciamos la ventanaA
        new VentanaA();
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva

Saludos.

Comment: Te agradezco tu tiempo, y disculpa pero, no entiendo como implementarlo    Por eJ: Ventana v = new Ventana();  v.setVisible(true); y luego this.showOnCreen(1,v)?

Comment: claro luego de instanciar tu Ventana v , debes llamar al metodo showOnScreen() y el primer parametro sera el numero del monitor donde debe verse y el segundo sera el JFrame, añadire un ejemplo